# Animating multiple headers that have same class

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css-animations

**Problem Solved**

Thank you Nalin Ranjan for your help!

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0n7wtjhv/) showing animation being applied to one header (the code is a modified version of this [GitHub project](https://github.com/moncef2006/https---github.com-moncef2006-project-2/blob/master/index.html)).

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q3kgtpm/#) showing animation being applied to all headers.

**Problem**

I want to apply the same animation to multiple headers. I have five headers with class fancy1, currently the animation is only being applied to the first header.

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3Lxw51p/) contains the code I use to get one header animated, although the animation isn't seeming to work in jsFiddle.

You can see in the screenshot below, the animation is mid way through running for the Las Vegas header.

[image]

**Old solution that animates one header**

```
 const text1 = document.querySelector('.fancy1');
    const strText1 = text1.textContent;
    const splitText1 = strText1.split("");
    text1.textContent = "";

for(let i=0; i<splitText1.length; i++){
    text1.innerHTML += "<span>"+ splitText1[i] + "</span>";
}

let char1 = 0;
let timer1 = setInterval(onTick,150);

function onTick(){
    const span1 = text1.querySelectorAll('span')[char1];
    span1.classList.add('fade');
    char1++;
  

    if (char1 === splitText1.length){
       
        complete1();
        return;
    }
}

function complete1(){
   
    clearInterval(timer1);
    timer1 = null;
}
```

**Failed solution 1**

I tried giving the five headers seperate class names - fancy1, fancy2, fancy3, fancy 4 and fancy5.

```
const text = document.getElementsByClassName(".fancy1");
Split(text)
const text = document.getElementsByClassName(".fancy2");
Split(text)

function Split(text){
const strText = text.textContent;
const splitText = strText.split("");
text.textContent = "";

for(let i=0; i<splitText.length; i++){
   
    text.innerHTML += "<span>"+ splitText[i] + "</span>";
   
}

let char = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick,150);
}

function onTick(){
    
    const span = text.querySelectorAll('span')[char];
    span.classList.add('fade');
   
    char++;
  
    if (char === splitText.length){
    
        complete();
        return;
    }
}

function complete(){
   
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
}
```

**Failed Solution 2**

I tried using global variables

```
const window.text = document.getElementsByClassName(".fancy1");
Split()
const window.text = document.getElementsByClassName(".fancy2");
Split()
const window.text = document.getElementsByClassName(".fancy3");
Split()
const window.text = document.getElementsByClassName(".fancy4");
Split()

function Split(){
const strText = (window.text).textContent;
const splitText = strText.split("");
text.textContent = "";

for(let i=0; i<splitText.length; i++){
   
    text.innerHTML += "<span>"+ splitText[i] + "</span>";
   
}

let char = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick,150);
}

function onTick(){
    
    const span = text.querySelectorAll('span')[char];
    span.classList.add('fade');
    char++;
    if (char === splitText.length){
       
        complete();
        return;
    }
}
function complete(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
}
```

**Failed solution 3 (based on Nalin Ranjan's reponse)**

After making a number of tweaks to Nalin Ranjan's soltuion, I was no longer getting erorr messages in the console log. But none of the animations were happening.

```
const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.fancy1');

headers.forEach(text => Split(text));

function Split(text){

const strText = text.textContent;
const splitText = strText.split("");
text.textContent = "";

for(let i=0; i<splitText.length; i++){
   
    text.innerHTML += "<span>"+ splitText[i] + "</span>";
   
}

window.char = 0;
window.timer = setInterval(onTick,1500);
window.text = text
window.splitText = splitText
}

function onTick(){
    
    const span = window.text.querySelectorAll('span')[window.char];
    span.classList.add('fade');
   
    window.char++;
  
  console.log(window.char)
  console.log(window.splitText.length)
    if (window.char === window.splitText.length){

        console.log("is it working?")
    
        complete();
        return;
    }
}

function complete(){
   
    clearInterval(timer);
    window.timer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns a single element as result, however you want to apply your function to multiple elements, so why not use `document.querySelectorAll`.

How about trying this...

```
const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.fancy1');

headers.forEach(header => Split(header));

function Split(text) {

  const strText = text.textContent;
  const splitText = strText.split("");
  text.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {

    text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";

  }

  let char = 0;
  let timer = setInterval(onTick, 150);

  function onTick() {
    const spans = text.querySelectorAll('span');
    const currentSpan = spans[char];
    currentSpan.classList.add('fade');

    char++;

    if (char === splitText.length) {

      complete();
      return;
    }
  }

  function complete() {

    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I added some extra comments to the bottom of my post

Comment: Could you please share full html css and js?

Comment: @RossSymonds, I overlooked it the first time, but I can now see a `const span = text.querySelectorAll('span')[char];`.. which again returns a collection, but then again in the subsequent line we are applying `span.classList.add('fade');` which again seems suspicious to do.. As even in this case, we should be doing `spans.forEach(span => span.classList.add('fade'))`. Don't you think? And perfect will be, if you can make a jsFiddle with the necessary HTML, CSS and JS, so that we can try our hands at in helping you.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly. Let's see if that works for you.

Comment: Annoyingly I still have not resolved the issue.

Comment: Please see the top of the post. I have included a jsFiddle. Fingers crossed I have included all neccesary information. And no uneccesary information.

Comment: It worked for me. Can you take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2q3kgtpm/#&togetherjs=hgc3T8cM1i). I have changed some code for demo.

Comment: Updated this answer as well.